# Is it possible to have an Android build.xml that supports 1.5, 1.6 and also supports different screen densities?

Tags: android, build

I know that I can have Eclipse build for 1.5 and 1.6 SDKs for different screen densities if I have the following snippet in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
```

and if I set up my assets in the following manner in `res` folder:

```
/res/drawable-hdpi-v4
/res/drawable-ldpi-v4
```

My default.properties has the following line:

```
# Indicates whether an apk should be generated for each density.
split.density=false
# Project target.
target=android-4
```

This setup allows me to create 1.5 and 1.6 builds in Eclipse IDE, but fails with the following error when I try to do a command line build.

```
Buildfile: build.xml
    [setup] Project Target: Android 1.6
    [setup] API level: 4
    [setup] WARNING: Attribute minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml (3) is lower than the project target API level (4)
Target "resource-src" does not exist in the project "<project-name>". It is used from target "compile".
```

This error comes up whether I use build.xml generated by 1.5 SDK or the 1.6 SDK (with -resource-src, -aidl targets).

I think that on commandline the build.xml is defaulting to 1.5 SDK, I dont know any way of making it work with 1.6+ SDKs and would appreciate any thoughts, comments on this.

My goal is have one script that with will compile for all Android SDKs while supporting different screen densities.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I should have answered this myself a while back considering I solved this issue. The problem here was Google changing the `<android-home>/tools/ant/main_rules.xml` file which is used for commandline compiles in Android 2.2 I think.

The answer is simple actually, I just updated my Android SDK to latest and in my build.xml file, I overwrote the targets defined in `<android-home>/tools/ant/main_rules.xml` that I needed to modify. This is the recommended way according to Google and now all my apps are built from Android 1.5 onwards.